# Get key name from perl hash using its value

Tags: perl

I've an hash of 4 members,say,

```
%hash = 
( 

xxx => 8,

yyy => 3,

zzz => 2,

aaa => 2,

)
```

But, here we know only "8,3,2,2" i.e.,values in that hash, how do I get and store the key name for the value "3" in specific? (without any hash reversing, as reversing will not return the repetitive elements)

Comment: So we don't go over what you've already done, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I've just sorted the hash based on values first, and reversed it.
so, it changed as,

8 => xxx,
3 => yyy,
2 => aaa,

it lefts out zzz due to reversing (tried mapping also - same results)

then by accessing key as "3" to extract its value to find the value (which was our original key to extract)

Comment: Update your question with the code that you've tried and isn't working. Note that `{}` is a hash reference, `()` is for creating a hash.

Comment: yeah, lets store that particular key value pair in new hash. @melpomene

Comment: its a hash reference @stevieb

Comment: Why do you have `%hash = {}`?

Comment: The code you showed doesn't create a hash with 4 elements. Is that really what you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By examining every key-value pair for the target value

```
@target_keys = grep { $hash{$_} eq $target_value } keys %hash;
```

If you're going to do this a lot, it does make sense to "reverse" the hash, but in the reversed hash use list references as the hash values so you can track when multiple keys in the original hash refer to the same value.

```
my %reverse_hash = ();
while (my ($k,$v) = each %hash) {
    push @{$reverse_hash}{$v}, $k;
}

...

@target_keys = @{$reverse_hash{$target_value} // []}
```

Comment: And, grep is working fine, Thank You !
But, do we have any pinpoint method of getting the any one key using its value even if two or more keys has same value?
like               $key = _____ { hash{$_} eq $target_value } keys %hash;

Comment: `($one_of_the_target_keys) = grep { $hash{$_} eq $target_val } keys %hash`

Comment: Better still: `use List::Util qw(first); my $key = first { hash{$_} eq $target_val } keys %hash`.  This will stop at the first key, rather than finding all the keys and then only using the first one.

Comment: @RameshAravindM: You need to update this in your question please.